How can I access Amplify Secrets From my React App
I'm writing right now a react app locally, which is deployed to amplify when I push the code.
In AWS Amplify Console I have two secrets, which I want to access in my react app code.
I tried to look in the Amplify docs but I found only this:
import { defineAuth, secret } from '@aws-amplify/backend';

export const auth = defineAuth({
  loginWith: {
    email: true,
    externalProviders: {
      facebook: {
        clientId: secret('foo'),
        clientSecret: secret('bar')
      }
    }
  }
});

I installed aws-amplify, but this module doesn't have a backend path, and the imported variables does not exist.
I tried to find the secrets in the AWS secret manager, but I couldn't see my amplify secrets there.
Maybe they are stored in a secret manager under different names?
My qtn is:
How can I access the amplify secrets through my react code?
Is there a way of getting the secrets like environment variables?
Something like: process.env.MY_SECRET
